# Rewrite with Nginx then replace cars in results

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want /search/i-love-bacon to become /results?search_query=I+love+bacon.

actually I can get approxymative results with:

```
rewrite "^/search/(\w*)\-(\w*)" "/results?search_query=$1+$2" permanent;
```

But I don't know how many terms I can have at entry, it can be 1 or 10 and here actually I get only 2 terms.

Have to works in these cases:

```
/search/mom                          to  /results?search_query=mom
/search/my-grandpa-is-old            to  /results?search_query=my+grandpa+is+old
/search/green-grass                  to  /results?search_query=green+grass
/search/birds-and-elephants-can-swim to  /results?search_query=birds+and+elephants+can+swim
```

Answer (score 0):

You could recursively rewrite `-` to `+` before rewriting `/search` to `/results`. The recursive rewrite could be internal.

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/search/(.*)-(.*)$ /search/$1+$2 last;
    rewrite ^/search/(.*)$ /results?search_query=$1 permanent;
    ...
}
```

The recursive rewrite needs to be inside a location block (if it is internal, i.e. uses `last`). Either `location /` or `location /search` would do.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.